# Stash: get_list do not show some entries

Tags: stash, regex

So, have a `exp:stash:set_list` chock full of entries, I'm using them all over the site and on this one I need to show a limit of 3 (simple), random (simple) BUT we need to **not** show some entries.

This would be how I'd go about it if stash worked like EE *but I know it wont work*, wondering what sort of regex would be required.

```
//I know this will fail
{exp:stash:get_list name="prod_list" limit="3" orderby="random" scope="site" match="not 32|244|2|66" against="entry_ids"}
… show the stuff
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For others and my future self, here's the regex solution:

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="prod_list"
    limit="3"
    match="#^((?!.*(32|244|2|66|etc)).*)$#"
    against="entryid"
    orderby="random"
    scope="site"}
        … spit out entries
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```